# How to change variables in link of foo?q=some&s=3&d=new

Tags: php, regex, get

Consider a php script visited with URL of `foo?q=some&s=3&d=new`. I wonder if there is a paractical method for parsing the url to create links with new variable (within php page). For example `foo?q=**another-word**&s=3&d=new` or `foo?q=another-word&s=**11**&d=new`

I am thinking of catching the requested URL by $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] then parsing with regex; but this is not a good idea in practice. There should be a handy way to parse variables attached to the php script. In fact, inverse action of GET method.

Comment: For "inverse action of GET method", do you want to propose an HTTP GIVE method? ;o)

Comment: No I meant something like parse_url but not dealing with the entire url; just only queries. Your idea is quite good; I just thought there might be a more specific function to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `$_GET` variable contains an already parsed array of the current query string. The array union operator `+` makes it easy to merge new values into that. [`http_build_query`](http://php.net/http_build_query) puts them back together into a query string:

```
echo 'foo?' . http_build_query(array('q' => 'another-word') + $_GET);
```

If you need more parsing of the URL to get `'foo'`, use [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) on the `REQUEST_URI`.

Answer (score 1):

What about using `http_build_query`?  http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php

It will allow you to build a query string from an array.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use [`parse_str`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php):

```
$query = 'q=some&s=3&d=new';
parse_str($query, $query_parsed);
$query_parsed['q'] = 'foo-bar';
$new_query = implode('&', array_map(create_function('$k, $v', 
                                   'return $k."=".urlencode($v);'), 
                          array_keys($query_parsed), $query_parsed));
echo $new_query;
```

Result is:

> q=foo-bar&s=3&d=new

Although, this method might look like "the hard way" :)

Comment: Certainly reinventing `http_build_query` is "doing it the hard way". :o)